# Excel division by 0 error when trying to average results of formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of percentages(column B), and another column next to it(column C) that calculates grades from the percentages using this formula:

`=IF(B3>=0.8,"5",IF(B3>=0.7,"4",IF(B3>=0.6,"3",IF(B3>=0.5,"2","1"))))`

When I try to average all the grades(column C) I get a division by 0 error.
Formula used to average:

`=AVERAGE(C3:C30)`

What is the problem here?

Comment: BTW your formula could be simplified to: `=MATCH(B3,{0,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to take an average of text strings.

Change your formula to:

```
=IF(B3>=0.8,5,IF(B3>=0.7,4,IF(B3>=0.6,3,IF(B3>=0.5,2,1))))
```

A number wrapped in quotes like `"4"`, is not actually a number, but rather text, you cannot take an `AVERAGE` of text values.

You can do a simple test to see if a number is actually a number. In D2 use `=ISNUMBER(C2)` if it returns `TRUE`, then it is a number.

Answer (score 8):

**An Array Formula will solve your problem:**

[image]

```
{=AVERAGE(VALUE(B1:B4))}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish this Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- **VALUE** Converts Text data into Numbers.
- Your Formula should written like

  `{=AVERAGE(VALUE(C3:C30))}`

Comment: + for use of VALUE, never come across this before